Proving an isomorphism $(V^* \otimes V)^G\cong End_{KG}(V)$
I am trying to prove the module isomorphism given below.
$$(V^* \otimes V)^G\cong End_{KG}(V)$$
where $V$ is a $KG-$module and $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$. Also, for a $KG-$module $X$, notice that $X^G$ is the $G$ invariant subspace of $X$. I am working with finite groups and finite dimensional spaces.
I tried the following mapping $\Phi: End_{KG}(V) \to (V^* \otimes V)^G$
$$\Phi(T)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}f_i\circ T\otimes T(v_j)$$ for all $T\in End_{KG}(V)$ where $\{f_i\},\{v_j\}$ are the bases of $V^*,V$ respectively and $n$ is the dimension of $V$.
However, I fail to prove it's $G-$invariancy. I must get $g\cdot \Phi(T)=\Phi(T)$ to have $\Phi(T)\in (V^* \otimes V)^G$. All I could get was the following.
$$g\cdot \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}f_i\circ T\otimes T(v_j) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}f_i\circ (g^{-1}T)\otimes g\cdot T(v_j).$$
When it failed, I tried a map in the opposite direction $\Psi: (V^* \otimes V)^G \to End_{KG}(V)$ by first defining the following on the basis of $V^* \otimes V$,
$$f_i\otimes v_j \mapsto f_i\cdot v_j$$
and then extending linearly to,
$$\Psi(f\otimes v) = \Psi(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i f_i\otimes \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j v_j) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\alpha_i\beta_j\Phi(f_i\otimes v_j) =\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\alpha_i\beta_j (f_i\cdot v_j).$$
In this situation, I fail to establish that it is Homomorphic under $G-$action. That is, $g\cdot  \Psi (f\otimes v) = \Psi \cdot g (f\otimes g).$ $RHS = \Psi(f\otimes g)$ because of $G-$invariancy. But the $$LHS = g\cdot \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\alpha_i\beta_j (f_i\cdot v_j) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\alpha_i\beta_j g\cdot (f_i\cdot v_j).$$
And I can't make $g$ disappear as needed.
Any hint in the right direction would be much appreciated.

You need to add the assumption that $V$ is finite-dimensional.

@MartinBrandenburg Yes. I have mentioned that at the beginning. I am working with finite groups and spaces.

First, try to write down a canonical $k$-linear isomorphism from $V^*\otimes V \rightarrow \text{End}_k(V)$, where k is the  base field. Now, show that this is a G-module homomorphism where G acts diagonally on the left and G acts on $\text{End}_k(V)$ by
$$g.\phi=g \circ \phi \circ g^{-1}$$ for $g\in G, ; \phi \in$ End$_k(V)$.
Now show that $\text{End}_k(V)^G= \text{End}_G(V)$.

You can see below a detailed answer.


First, try to write down a canonical $k$-linear isomorphism from $V^*\otimes V \rightarrow \text{End}_k(V)$, where k is the  base field.

Now, show that this is a G-module homomorphism where G acts diagonally on the left and G acts on $\text{End}_k(V)$ by
$$g.\phi=g \circ \phi \circ g^{-1}$$ for $g\in G, \; \phi \in$ End$_k(V)$.

Now show that $\text{End}_k(V)^G= \text{End}_G(V)$, so that restricting the map from Step 1 to the subspace of $G-$invariants gives an isomorphism $(V^*\otimes V)^G \rightarrow (\text{End}_k(V))^G=\text{End}_G(V)$.


In detail:

The map should be $\Psi: V^* \otimes V \ni f \otimes v \mapsto (w\mapsto f(w)v) \in \text{End}_k(V)$. The inverse map requires fixing basis, say $\{v_i\}$ is a basis for $V$ and $\{f_i\}$ the dual basis, then the inverse map is $T \mapsto \sum_{i}f_j(T(v_i)) f_i\otimes v_j$.
Observe that $$\Psi(g.(f\otimes v))=\Psi(g.f\otimes gv)= \Psi(f \circ g^{-1}\otimes gv) = [w\mapsto (f\circ g^{-1}(w))gv] = [w\mapsto g( (f\circ g^{-1})(w)v)] \\=g \circ [w \mapsto f(w)v] \circ g^{-1}\\ =g.[w \mapsto f(w)v] $$
so that $\Psi$ is indeed a $G-$module map.
This is just definition of what it means for $\phi \in \text{End}_k(V)$ to be in $\text{End}_G(V)$, since $g\circ \phi \circ g^{-1} = \phi \iff g\circ \phi = \phi \circ g$.


Since the $g$ action on $(V^*\otimes V)^G$ is invariant, shouldn't that imply $g.[w\mapsto f(w)v] = [w\mapsto f(w)v]$ ?

If $f \otimes v \in (V^\otimes V)^G$, then yes. This would be a consequence of the observation in Step 2. In general, you might not have the pure tensors to live in the invariant space $(V^\otimes V)^G$.

I mean, for the representation to be homomorphic, $\Psi(g.(f\otimes v)) = g.\Psi(f\otimes v)$ should hold. But, since $\Psi(g.(f\otimes v)) = \Psi(f\otimes v)$ shouldn't that imply $g.\Psi(f\otimes v) = \Psi(f\otimes v)$ ?

For an arbitrary element $f\otimes v \in V^\otimes V$,  $g. (f\otimes v)= f  \circ g^{-1} \otimes g.v$ by definition of how $G$ acts on $V^ \otimes V$. There's no reason for $g.(f\otimes v)$ to be equal to $f \otimes v$ apriori, unless you're assuming it's in the invariant subspace.

More precisely, ${f_i \otimes v_j}$ do not, in general, form a basis for $(V^* \otimes V)^G$ if ${f_i}, {v_j}$ are (dual, if you want) basis for $V^*, V$ respectively. But what you can do is construct a map as in Step 1, and show that it's a homomorphism of $G-$modules (as in Step 2), and then restrict it to the subspace of invariants. I've edited the step 3 to make it clearer.

Makes sense. Actually, your inverse map in step 1 was what I was searching for precisely. Accepted.
